# Add column with group-by length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns. I want to add a new column containing the number of values for which two values are the same.

For example, suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
    x   y
0   1   5
1   2   7
2   3   2
3   7   3
4   2   7
5   6   5
6   5   3
7   2   7
8   2   2
```

I want to add a third column that contains the number of values for which both `x` and `y` are the same. The desired output here would be

```
x   y   frequency
0   1   5   1
1   2   7   3
2   3   2   1
3   7   3   1
4   2   7   3
5   6   5   1
6   5   3   1
7   2   7   3
8   2   2   1
```

For instance, all rows with `(x, y) = (2, 7)` equal three because `(2, 7)` appears three times in the dataframe.

One way to get the output is to create a "hash" (i.e., `df['hash'] = df['x'].astype(str) + ',' + df['y'].astype(str)` followed by `df['frequency'] = df['hash'].map(collections.Counter(df['hash'))`), but can we do this directly with group-by? The frequency column is exactly equal to the entry's group in `df.groupby(['x', 'y'])`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IIUC this will work for you:

```py
df['frequency'] = df.groupby(['x','y'])['y'].transform('size')
```

Output:

```
   x  y  frequency
0  1  5          1
1  2  7          3
2  3  2          1
3  7  3          1
4  2  7          3
5  6  5          1
6  5  3          1
7  2  7          3
8  2  2          1
```